# Access resources at base package in Java?

Tags: java, properties, resources

I don't like having my properties files in `resources/mypackage/.../somepackage/resourcefile.properties` and would rather have them just in `resources/resourcefile.properties`. Is that somehow possible without:

1. being forced to write `MyApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("../../../../../../../../resources/resourcefile.properties")` or
2. it not working in Tomcat when using `SomeClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resourcefile.properties")` ?

Answer (score 4):

Put in a leading slash to designate the root package:

```
SomeClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resourcefile.properties")
```

Comment: Are you sure that works? I thought each virtual machine only has one class loader and thus the one of Tomcat doesn't have the base package directory as root but instead some different directory.

Comment: `Class.getResourceAsStream()` loads resources from the class path, not the file system. All package names on the class path share the same root, although hierarchical class loaders may enforce visibility constraints (i.e. you can see resources from your own package or any parents, but not from sibling packages).